# WPF: Progress bar with indeterminent duration?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, progress-bar

In WinForms you could set a progress bar to loop endlessly to indicate that you don't know how long it will take. How would I do that in WPF?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally like the approach Visual Studio 2010 takes.  They use an animation of a small, looping series of dots (with varying intensity).  They just animate the dots circling in the center of the window in question.

In WPF, this is trivial - just animate a rotation of a small drawing of a circle of dots with the opacity set correctly up front.

I find it very intuitive, small, and unintrusive.

Comment: That can look nicers, but is way too much to learn for what needs to be quick and easy page.

Comment: In Windows Forms, it was tough to implement.  In WPF, it's very, very easy (especially if you're using Blend).

Answer (score 0):

Is a *progress bar* the right widget for this?  You are unable to indicate a % complete, since you "don't know how long it will take".  Maybe an animation of some sort (like the Windows files-disappearing-into-thin-air-while-deleting effect) to show that activity is still going on would be better.  But a "progress" bar that simply resets to zero because there is still more work to do just looks dumb to me.

Comment: It's not the same effect as constantly filling from 0 to 100 and then resetting. Progress bars in indeterminate mode are more like a small block of color constantly moving along the bar (or, in Vista and later, a solid yellow bar with a moving highlight). It's not the greatest animation, but it's fairly standard in Windows and is not easily confused with the logout process from Office Space.